# Conversion of euro symbol

Tags: java, unicode, ascii, currency, euro

In my web application euro (€) symbol is being converted to question mark (?). It is built on Java. The code is fine but when deployed the EAR on WAS 6.0 sometimes it works fine but sometimes it converts the € to a ?.

Is this something related to ASCII conversion? How to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what ascii code did you use for it? is it 128?

Answer (score 4):

Now `€` or (u-escaped) `"\u20AC"`may be used.

The web page must **not** be encoded in ISO-8859-1, but rather UTF-8. Let's assume that.

Used as `€` in java source text, the editor encoding and the javac compiler encoding must be UTF-8.

Use in a JSP the encoding must be UTF-8 too, but now the jspc compiler runs on the final server and there must use UTF-8 too.

Remains the database where the encoding has to fit too.

Alternative encodings to UTF-8 exist, but are problematic. ISO-8859-15 or so has the Euro symbol, but has not all the characters of ISO-8859-1, because all browsers (but not java) interpret ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) as Windows-1252 (Windows Latin-1) having more characters like comma like quotes and a special hyphen. Since HTML 5 this became a required standard.

Windows-1252 is the only sensible encoding alternative, but covers just a couple of European languages. There the code is 0x80 (128) as seen when doing

```
byte[] cp1252 = "\u20AC".getBytes("Windows-1252");
// { -128 }
```

The source of the error may stem from copying in Windows.

Comment: Thank you very much Joop for the detailed expliantion. It did work :)

Answer (score 0):

You should html-escape special characters. For example:

```
€ = &euro;
```

That way you always have plain ascii in your html and don't have to worry about encodings.